# Select rows with condition on a column in pandas (plus avoiding duplicates)

Tags: python, pandas

I've a question about a specific problem in pandas:
I have in a df a column with the following values:

```
5
4
3
2
1
0
0
0
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

I want to select all the rows from the first 5 to the last 0:

```
5
4
3
2
1
0
0
0
0
```

I tried with drop duplicates, but i loose the last three zeroes.
I'm thinking aboutusing a for cycle and stop when the i-th value of the column is greater than the i-1 value, but i don't know how to make such a cycle for a dataframe in pandas.
Can someone help me?

Thank you in advance, I hope I've explained the problem clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`DataFrame.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) to compare with the next row, and keep only those that are less or equal than the previous. Here I use `np.r_` to include the first value too:

```
import numpy as np
df[np.r_[True, df.col.le(df.col.shift()).to_numpy()[1:]]]

   col
0    5
1    4
2    3
3    2
4    1
5    0
6    0
7    0
8    0
```

Answer (score 0):

Let us try **[`cummax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cummax.html)**:

```
s = df['col']
df.loc[s.eq(5).cummax() & s[::-1].eq(0).cummax()]
```

---

```
   col
0    5
1    4
2    3
3    2
4    1
5    0
6    0
7    0
8    0
```